# $\langle x\rangle=\int \phi(x)^2 x \, dx $

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $\displaystyle \phi(x)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a}}e^{\dfrac{-|x|}{a}}$ where $a\geq 0$

let $\displaystyle \langle A\rangle=\int \phi(x)^2 A \, dx=$

- Calculate : $\langle x\rangle$ and $\langle x^2\rangle$

note that :

[image]
here is what they did in solution but i can't get it could someone elaborate it please :

$$\begin{align*}
\langle x\rangle&=\int \phi(x)^2 x \, dx \\
&=\dfrac{1}{a}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x \left(e^{\dfrac{-|x|}{a}}\right)^2 \, dx \\
&=\frac{1}{a}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{0}xe^{\dfrac{2x}{a}} \, dx + \int_0^{+\infty} xe^{\dfrac{-2x}{a}} \, dx\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{a}\left(-( \frac{a}{2})^2+( \frac{a}{2})^2\right)
&=0
\end{align*}$$

[image]

Comment: you should take your time and type your problem with Mathjax/Latex syntax.

Comment: $\langle A\rangle$ is standard notation; $<A>$ is not. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy i really don't know

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Copy the problem.
Step 2: They just substituted the e function in for phi.$$ $$

Step 3: They distributed the power of 2 into the exponent, then split the integral at x=0 to account for the absolute value (they should have done this in two steps).
$$ $$
Step 4: They show that two integrals have opposite value, thus their sum is zero.

(Step 5 for second part of question): 0^2 is zero

Comment: could you write step by step to see right please

Comment: Is the picture your attempted solution or a key?

Comment: it's solution  provided by professor

Comment: it says solve for x and x^2 vectors, looks like the prof solved for delta u!?